# Defining consistency checks for the content of larger documents

Tags: best-practices, warnings

Many of us have encountered this: you're writing a larger paper / proposal / book, possibly collaboratively with multiple authors with different writing styles or English flavors/flavours, ending up with an inconsistent mess or a lot of manual consistency checks. Worse: you keep repeating these over and over again after you or others forgot that you agreed on some spelling...

Is there a (simple enough) way within latex/tex that allows me to define a couple common mistakes and search the whole "content" of the document to issue warnings if found or even just replace them?

For example, can i somehow put something like this in the preamble?

```
\warn{dataset}  % data set
\warn{pretrained}  % pre-trained
\warn{neighborhood}  % neighbourhood
\warn{home page}  % homepage
\warn{Fig.}  % Figure

% or even
\replace{dataset}{data set}
\replace{pretrained}{pre-trained}
\replace{neighborhood}{neighbourhood}
\replace{home page}{homepage}
\replace{Fig.}{Figure}
```

I'm aware that i could write a simple build-script that includes some `grep` or `sed` (and have done so before when i was annoyed enough), but nowadays i'd prefer some solution that works on sharelatex/overleaf alike platforms as well, so from within latex itself.

Answer (score 2):

In `pdfcsplain`, there is `\mubyte` `\endmubyte` pair initialized, so the solution of your task is quite simple:

```
\def\replace#1#2{\expandafter \mubyte \csname repl:#1\endcsname #1\endmubyte
   \expandafter\def \csname repl:#1\endcsname{#2}}

\replace{dataset}{data set}
\replace{pretrained}{pre-trained}
\replace{neighborhood}{neighbourhood}
\replace{home page}{homepage}
\replace{Fig.}{Figure}

Try dataset or home page.  % result: Try data set or homepage.

\bye
```

Note that you can use `pdfcsplain` at Overleaf when the file with the name `latexmkrc` is present and its contents is:

```
 $pdflatex = 'pdfcsplain %O %S';
```

**Edit** If you explicitly needs LaTeX solution (it was not clear from the question) then you can initialize the `pdflatex` format by

```
pdftex -ini -etex -enc pdflatex.ini
```

and then use it: If the generated file `pdflatex.fmt` is in current directory then you can run `pdftex -fmt pdflatex document` or simply `latex document`. Note the `-enc` option when format is generated: it activates the encTeX extension of pdfTeX with mentioned primitives `\mubyte` and `\endmubyte`. The LaTeX example for your question can be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\replace#1#2{\expandafter \mubyte \csname repl:#1\endcsname #1\endmubyte
   \expandafter\def \csname repl:#1\endcsname{#2}}

\replace{dataset}{data set}
\replace{pretrained}{pre-trained}
\replace{neighborhood}{neighbourhood}
\replace{home page}{homepage}
\replace{Fig.}{Figure}

\mubytein=1

\begin{document}

Try dataset or home page.  % result: Try data set or homepage.

\end{document}
```

Comment: i like the answer, but as soon as i include the `latexmkrc` you mentioned on overleaf, i cannot compile a standard latex article anymore :-/

Comment: @JörnHees Sory, your question was: "Is there a (simple enough) way within latex/*tex*". My answer is concerned to TeX, no LaTeX. I hope that somebody else give LaTeX specific answer.

Comment: The `\mubyte` ... `\endmubute` pair can be activated in pdfLaTeX too, but format must be re-generated. But I don't know how user can use his own format *.fmt at Overleaf.

Comment: @JörnHees I see that nobody else answers. I added the LaTeX-like solution of your question. It is simple to try it in local computer - it works. I don't know how to use such re-generated format at Overleaf. Of course, the simple copy of `pdflatex.fmt` will not work because the generated binary file `pdflatex.fmt` is strictly engine-dependent: Only a little version change of the engine causes that you must re-generate formats again. Maybe you can put another question here: how to use generated formats at Overleaf.